# ruby - ActiveRecord multiple databases for the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-server, activerecord, multiple-databases

We have a vendor-provided application that is using a MSSQL database as backend.
We have multiple instances of this application, and thus multiple databases / databases servers hosting the same database model but with different data.

I'm trying to develop a very simple "browsing tool" to provide a single view of all theses databases (read only).

I'm using Sinatra/ActiveRecord/ActiveRecord-SqlServer-Adapter and I have my models overloaded to comply with the database model.

What I'm now looking for is a way to request all the databases at once and aggregate all the results.

Is there any way to do this in vanilla ActiveRecord? Using a gem?
I found the `db-charmer` gem that does something like that, but's it's only compatible with MySQL and I can't get it to work without rails anyway.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a gem that I was able to hack to do what I need.

I used [`Octopus`](https://github.com/tchandy/octopus/) and its sharding capabilities, and I added a simple method to my base controller class (that all my other controllers are based off of) that looks like this:

```
def on_all_shards(&block)
  Octopus.config[:shards].each.collect do |shard, shard_config|
    Octopus.using(shard) do
      yield
    end
  end
end
```

Then in my controllers, whenever I need to aggregate the results of all my shards if just do:

```
on_all_shards do
  Model.first
end
```

In this case, I would get an array of the first record of this Model/table from each database (1 record / database).

Thank you guys for pointing me to the right direction (ActiveRecord connection/connection_pool management)!

Answer (score 2):

This won't be a specific answer to your question, but may help you nonetheless

--

**Models**

We've been working on a [multi-tenancy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy) system lately, and needed to access multiple databases

The "way" to do it is actually rather simple - but only if you wanted to do it at *model* level. Anything else & you've lost me, sorry.

At model level, each time you initialize an instance of an object (IE load a `model`), Rails will access the database, and consequently populate the ruby object with the required attributes. A "trick" to making a multi-tenant system (with multiple database connections) is to **inherit from different models**

Here's an example:

```
#app/models/option.rb
Class Option < Admin
   ...
end

#lib/admin.rb
Class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true 
  establish_connection "#{Rails.env}_admin"
end

#config/database.yml
production_admin:
  your: ____
  database: ____
  values: ____
```

This allows you to connect to a different database for your `Option` model; providing you with the ability to load the various files / settings to make it work correctly

Whilst I don't think this will address your issue directly (you want to access multiple databases simultaneously), I hope it will give you an idea

--

**Database**

The bottom line here is that if you want to connect to multiple database simultaneously, you'll likely want to look at identifying the database for the model, and then setting the connection type in the model.

I'm not exactly sure as to whether you're trying to load the data into *different* model objects, or the same one. If it's through *multiple* object, you might be able to pull off what I mentioned above, dynamically setting the database as required

--

That's all I've got I'm afraid

Comment: I've looked at what you are describing, but I need to have the same model pull data from multiple databases (all the databases having the exact same schema, only the data inside are different).

Answer (score 1):

If you had a list of all the connections you could do something like

```
connection_specs.collect do |spec|
  Model.establish_connection(spec)
  Model.all
end
```

or initialize some base classes somewhere

```
db_klasses = connection_specs.collect do |spec|
  Class.new(ActiveRecord::Base) do
    establish_connection(spec)
  end
end
```

and then

```
db_klasses.collect do |db_klass|
  db_klass.connection_pool.with_connection do
    Model.all
  end
end
```

Comment: Seems nice, but won't it reconnect to each database for each request?

Comment: Yea, I suppose you could get around that by dynamically defining a base class for each connection (maybe in an initializer?) and then using with_connection. That should take advantage of the connection pool

Comment: I tried it, but ActiveRecord is complaining about Anonymous class not being allowed... Any way to fixe that?

Comment: Ok, I've got this a little bit further, by adding a |klass| block parameter to Class.new and naming the class using Object.const_set(spec[:database].classify, klass) inside the block.
The problem is, when inside the "model" loop, ActiveRecord throw a ConnectionNotEstablished error

Comment: Are you still calling establish_connection in the class definition?